# How to fill color in the icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new in flutter. I am using multiple theme(i.e. dark mode) in the app. So, When we use icon in different theme, automatically take background color according to the theme. I want background color of theme but not inside the icon.

Example:
I am using youtube's icon in dark theme so look like below,

[image]

But i want to like below,

[image]

I am using

```
Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.youtube,
    color: Colors.red
)
```

So how to fill the color white in this icon ? (Or also you can suggest me to do that in proper as well as better way to implement)

(so, i can use white filled icon in every theme)

Comment: try this . Icon(
          Icons.place,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),

Comment: Are you using an image for the YouTube icon? or a combination of `Icon`s to create the logo

Comment: @Viren V Varasadiya It's change color from red to black but i want to change the play button inside the youtube icon color white.

Comment: @Sidak I am use FontAwesomeIcons and it's just example.

Comment: is it fine for you. if some part outside icon also stay wight? if yes then you can wrap icon with container and give color to white.

Comment: Sorry @VirenVVarasadiya but it's not good looking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `Stack` to place a filled `Container` under your icon like so:

```dart
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), // Modify this till it fills the color properly
          color: Colors.white, // Color
        ),
      ),
      Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.youtube, // Icon
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      ),
    ])
```

Since its a container, you can also modify its shape in case there are random icon shapes that a normal square does not help in :P

I tried filling the icon `play_circle_filled` with green using this on DartPad and it gave me this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I think there could be a modification in Sidak's solution. Instead of using a container in the background, we could use the same Icon of the desired color in the background using the stack widget.

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), // Modify this till it fills the color properly
          color: Colors.white, // Color
        ),
      ),
      Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.youtube, // Icon
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      ),
    ])
```